# Private IP address of Azure VM being returned as address in WSDL file when accessing WSDL file from browser connected to an Azure Application Gateway

Tags: web-services, azure, soap, wsdl, aws-api-gateway

I have a SOAP Service running on tomcat that is deployed in an Azure Scaling Set.  I have an Azure Application gateway that is font ending the scale set.   When I try to access the wsdl (/service?wsdl) file via a web browser using the Application Gateway DNS, the wsdl that is returned has the private IP addresses of the VM that processed the file in it.  This prevents the endpoints from being accessed since they are private.  If I access the wsdl going directly to the back end VM's DNS name, the address returned contains the public host name of the VM that I sent the request to and can be accessed since its public.  I don't have this problem when I deploy a similar deployment in the AWS environment using AWS ELB in front of the scaling group.

I am able to get this to work by configuring tomcat connector to use proxyName and proxyPort to specify the host name of the Azure Application Gateway.  However, there are other SOAP clients that are required to access the back end VMs directly on that same connector, and by specifying the proxy parameters for the connector forces them to go through the Azure application gateway as well.

I realize that a different tomcat connector can be configured to address this, but this is not an optimal solution for the back end application.

So to the question.  Is there some Azure Application gateway configuration setting that I can change, so I can make this work like AWS ELB and not have to use the proxyName tomcat parameter?

Thanks.